# how to load Tree inside JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, tree, jcombobox

How can I show a tree inside a JComboBox popup?

Here is example tree:

```
Theoretical computer science 
           Mathematical logic 
            Automata theory 
Algorithms and data structures
           Analysis of algorithms
           Algorithms
```

Comment: Why not use a JTree (in a JScrollPane if needed) instead?

Answer (score 2):

There is no default way to put a tree in a combo box.  There are a couple of options:

If you can give allowing expansion of nodes, you can achieve a similar effect by adding space before some of the options in a standard JComobBox.  Or even space and a dash in front of leaf options.

If you need expansion of nodes, then a better option would be to add a popup that appears below a button that listens for selections of items in the tree.  Something like this might be a better choice depending on how your GUI is laid out.

Comment: A simple JMenu instead JComboBox, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . i Think i will try the second option

Answer (score 0):

When swinglabs was active there used to be `JXComboBox` that allows you to have other components in the dropdown like a JTable/JTree.
Check [here](http://java.net/projects/swingx/) or [here](http://java.net/projects/swinglabs-demos/) you may find the source for it or the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i can't file the example inside swinglabs package    ! Can you give the example code ?

Answer (score 0):

You coud write your own renderer and put a treenode picture in front of the returning label for the subnodes.

Something like:

```
private static class NodeComboBoxRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    protected DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel renderer = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if(value.isSubNode()) { //something to find out
            renderer.setIcon("here comes the resource");
        }
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the `TreeComboBox` of mindgame ([link](https://code.google.com/p/mindgame-swing-components/source/browse/trunk/MindGameSwingComponents/source/org/mindgame/swing/components/TreeComboBox.java?r=41)). It just requires the class `AbstractComboBoxUI` of the same project.