# Is it possible to add a Tree inside a JCombobox?

Tags: java, swing, tree, jcombobox

Since I have too many options in my JComboBox, I thought maybe regrouping them based on their type in different nodes and let the user expand or collapse them depending on which type they like would be a good idea. This would improve the readability of the JComboBox and save the user a lot of time scrolling down or up looking for their option.

The question now is, is it possible to add a tree in a JComboBox?

The closest thing to a solution I have found on SO is this one: [One Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314207/how-to-load-tree-inside-jcombobox)

The person who came up with the alternative is suggesting the following:

> If you need expansion of nodes, then a better option would be to add a
> popup that appears below a button that listens for selections of items
> in the tree. Something like this might be a better choice depending on
> how your GUI is laid out.

But, and unless I misunderstood what they are saying, they are not adding the tree inside the JComboBox, which is really what I want here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can replace `JList` in popup component by `JTree`. But you need also to provide communication between `ComboBoxModel` and `TreeModel` (when an item is selected in `JTree`, it will also selected in `JComboBox` and vice versa). For example you can build implementation of `ComboBoxModel`, that has a `TreeModel` as delegate, and provides  linearization of your tree each time when your `TreeModel` changes (fires a `TreeModelEvent`), to get the item list for combobox. Also you need to provide reaction for mouse/key events in your tree, to update selection in your combobox.

Here is the method you can use to set any component as popup of a `JComboBox` (in your case it should be a `JScrollPane` that wraps your `JTree`):

```
/**
 * Sets the custom component as popup component for the combo-box.
 *
 * @param combo combo-box to get new popup component.
 * @param comp new popup component.
 * @param widthIncr width increment for pop-up.
 * @param heightIncr height increment for pop-up.
 */
public static void setPopupComponent(JComboBox<?> combo, Component comp, int widthIncr, int heightIncr) {
    final ComboPopup popup = (ComboPopup) combo.getUI().getAccessibleChild(combo, 0);
    if (popup instanceof Container) {
        final Container c = (Container) popup;
        c.removeAll();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        c.add(comp);
        final Dimension size = comp.getPreferredSize();
        size.width += widthIncr;
        size.height += heightIncr;
        c.setPreferredSize(size);
    }
}
```

Parameters `widthIncr` and `heightIncr` could be used for some Look-and-Feels to better adopt default width/heght of popup in your combobox.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Just one final question if you don't mind, and unless I didn't fully get it, using the `setPopupComponent` will add the JTree component and its nodes to the JComboBox, right?

Comment: @JesseJames this method removes the standard list from the popup component and adds to popup any component you transfer into this method. It may be `JTree`, `JTable` or any custom component (for example panel tha holds a table and a filter field). If you only need a tree use: `setPopupComponent(myCombo, new JScrollPane(myTree), 0, 0)`. Where `myCombo` is your combobox and `myTree` is your tree.